# The space $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}$ and it's norm for $d\in\mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, vector-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^{n}$ be open. Consider the space
$$H^{1}\left(\Omega\right):=\left\{f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right):\text{grad }f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{n}\right\}$$
where $\text{grad}$ is the vector-valued gradient. I consider this space together with the norm
$$\|g\|_{H_{1}\left(\Omega\right)}:=\left(\|g\|^{2}_{L_{2}\left(\Omega\right)}+\|\text{grad g}\|^{2}_{L_{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
which can be identified as the corresponding graph-norm.

**My problems:** I am finding it hard to clearly understand what the space $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}$ should look like, where $d\in\mathbb N$. Am I correct in my thinking that this space should be
$$H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}=\left\{\phi=(\phi_{i})_{i\in\left\{1,\dots,d\right\}}\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}:\text{grad }\phi_{i}\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{n}\text{ for each }i\in\left\{1,\dots,d\right\}\right\}?$$
Am I correct in thinking that the corresponding norm in this case is
$$\|\phi\|_{H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}}=\left(\|\phi\|^{2}_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}}+\sum_{i=1}^{d}\|\text{grad }\phi_{i}\|^{2}_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}?$$
If this is correct, is there some way to remove the sum in the sum of norms of the gradient parts, and present this more elegantly or concisely?

Comment: Looks correct. The sum of the norms of the gradients has to be present in the norm of $H^1(\Omega)^d$, one way or the other. You can also write it as the Frobenius norm of the (weak) Jacobian of $\phi$.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an answer and go into more detail on the how it can be written as the Frobenius norm of the (weak) Jacobian of $\phi$?

Comment: If you expand $\sum \|\nabla \phi_i\|_{L^2}^2$ you get exactly that Frobenius norm.